# Lightning Components Markup: is there anything like <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!whatever}">

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to control that some parts of the component markup will be conditionally rendered. In VF I used this pattern:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!whatever}">
    <div>this appearance should be controlled by the boolean "whatever"</div>
<apex:outputPanel>
```

Is there something comparable in LC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in Lightning we have [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_if.htm) <strike>and [aura:renderIf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_renderIf.htm)</strike> (edit: aura:renderIf is deprecated and should not be used).

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.someArray.length>0}">
    Has values
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        Does not have values
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```